# How to pass list to stored procedure

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, sql-server-2008-r2

I am trying to pass a list to a SQL Server 2008 R2 using user defined table types but get some errors.

My code is:

```
public int DAL_SaveIncramentSalary(tbl_Employee_Master obj, List<dtIncrementSalary> tbl)
{
        try
        {
            SqlParameter[] objSqlParameter = new SqlParameter[4];
            objSqlParameter[0] = new SqlParameter("@Company_ID", obj.Company_ID);
            objSqlParameter[1] = new SqlParameter("@Employee_ID", obj.Employee_ID);
            objSqlParameter[2] = new SqlParameter("@Salary_Month", obj.Govt_DA);
            objSqlParameter[3] = new SqlParameter("@dt", SqlDbType.Structured);
            objSqlParameter[3].Value = tbl;
            objSqlParameter[3].Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;

            DataSet fdd = SqlHelper.ExecuteDataset(_cnnString2, "usp_Insert_Increment_Salary_List", CommandType.StoredProcedure, objSqlParameter);

            DataSet fddd = SqlHelper.ExecuteDataset(_cnnString2, "usp_Insert_Increment_Salary_List", objSqlParameter);

            DataSet ds = SqlHelper.ExecuteDataset(_cnnString2, CommandType.StoredProcedure, "usp_Insert_Increment_Salary_List", objSqlParameter);

            return SqlHelper.ExecuteNonQuery(_cnnString2, CommandType.StoredProcedure, "usp_Insert_Increment_Salary_List", objSqlParameter);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception(ex.Message);
        }
}
```

I got errors like these:

> Dataset dff error : Parameter count does not match Parameter Value count.
>
> DataSet fddd error : Failed to convert parameter value from a List`1 to a IEnumerable`1.
>
> DataSet ds error :Failed to convert parameter value from a List`1 to a IEnumerable`1.

Comment: can you also show the procedure definition ?

Comment: I understand that the table has a table-valued parameter and you must have created a udt for it but I am interested to see the procedure definition...

Comment: alter PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_Insert_Increment_Salary_List]    
(@Company_ID int,@Employee_ID int,@Salary_Month int,@dt dtIncrementSalary readonly) AS BEGIN select * from @dt END