# How to pass list to stored procedure and return another list

Tags: jquery, asp.net, stored-procedures

I found two other questions but they did not help me, [Question 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35647981/how-to-pass-list-to-stored-procedure) & [Question 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35651097/how-to-pass-list-to-stored-procedure)

I am working on an ASP.NET project. I am using stored procedures to retrieve and insert data to and from database.

I have two dropdown lists with two checkbox as shown in the screenshot here:

[image: [Image dropdown]]

HTML markup:

```
    //---------- Shop Dropdown ---------
    <div>
        <label>Shop</label>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="input-group">
                <select class="form-control" id="ShopId">
                    <option value="0">---Select Shop---</option>
                    <option value="1" id="shopidone1">SHOP 1</option>
                    <option value="2" id="shopidone1">New Shop</option>
                    <option value="3" id="shopidone1">Lat Shop</option>
                </select>
                <span class="input-group-addon">
                    <label>
                        <span id="all" class="all">
                            <input type="checkbox" id="ShopCheckbox" value="1">
                        </span>
                        <span>All</span> 
                    </label>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    //---------- Category Dropdown ----------
    <div>
        <label class="lblCategory">Category</label>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="input-group">
                <select class="form-control" id="CategoryId">
                    <option>---Select Category---</option>
                </select>
                <span class="input-group-addon">
                    <label>
                        <span>
                            <input type="checkbox" name="" value="" id="CategoryCheckbox">
                        </span>
                        <span>All</span> 
                    </label>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

When I select a shop from the combo I pass shopid and get corresponding category.

jQuery:

```
     var ShopIdval = '{"shopid":"' + ShopId + '"}';
     ShopIdval = '"ShopIdvalBO":' + ShopIdval + '';

     var CategoryMaster = '{' + ShopIdval + ',"pageSession":"' + pageSession + '"}';

     $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: "AnalysisOfSalesByItem.aspx/GetCategory",
         contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
         data: CategoryMaster,
         dataType: "json",
         success: function (data) {
             Categoryappend(data.d);
         },
         error: function (msg) { }
     });
```

Then I call the stored procedure from my datalayer:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spcategorycomboAnalysisSales] 
    @shopid AS INT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    SELECT *
    FROM shopitemcategory sc, itemcategory ic 
    WHERE sc.itemcategoryid = ic.itemcategoryid 
      AND sc.shopid = @shopid 
    ORDER BY sc.itemcategoryid  

    SET NOCOUNT OFF
END
```

It's working perfectly and when I select a shop, corresponding category is loaded in the combo.

What I want is, when I click the check box I want to load all category values. Actually if I want to load all category its easy. But I am not loading all the shops in the drop down list, so I want all the category with the shops in the dropdown.

I am thinking If I could pass the list of shops in another stored procedure, then I can get the desired Ite

How do I do that?

Comment: Sorry it's unclear what the problem is?

Comment: when clicking the `checkbox of Shop` I want to pass the Shop Ids in the drop down to SP, so that I can return all related Category with thos Ids

Comment: the `shopId` and not the value of the option value?

Comment: Iam sorry, i meant the value

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: I've made fiddle **[here](http://jsbin.com/kufojeliho/edit?html,js,output)** let me know how you get on

Comment: Ok, how do I pass it into an SP

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11105413/3793448) answer